# Unable to download CSV from searchkit result

Tags: upgrade

After CiviCRM upgrade from 5.58.1 to 5.65.2, Download csv from search kit display fails (progress bar freezes and does not complete).

Checked CiviCRM and Wordpress logs for any errors, but nothing was logged. Any pointers to debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in CiviCRM 5.65.x and [was fixed as part of 5.67.x](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27417) release.

You can either upgrade CiviCRM to 5.67.x or apply [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27417.diff)

HTH

Pradeep